# Python - Mechanize. Having trouble with CSRF token /" referer header "

Tags: python, mechanize, csrf, referrer, clientform

Part of a form seems to be echoed back when I submit, generating an error.

Is there a class I need to use to manipulate this?

```
div style='display:none'/ input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='dbd2cb6627a3b7b68075e5d318c392de' /
```

There's also this unknown Javascript which might be the issue.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-28758203-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'someurl.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {<br>
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';<br>
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })(); (/script)
<br>
meta name="google-site-verification" content="M79TumRrI0FXdpZbUqm7J3yhE4Mi_KMOpTHvB1n7DpI" /
```

I've been searching quite a while for this.

Comment: Please frame your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

As the question in itself is not clear, but I think you are stuck with :

`mechanize` doesn't does `javascript`. Any js content is simple string to `mechanize` since it looks at a `webpage - js`.

Consider this : http://github.com/davisp/python-spidermonkey/tree/master

This seems to solve this problem.